# Subclassing UIView with IBOutlets

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitableview, iboutlet

I've been trying for a long time to add IBOutlets to a UIView.
Well, it seems impossible.
I created a class called "RecessCell".
The file's owner's class is "RecessCell" and the view object's class is RecessCell.
I created an outlet called "betweenPeriods" and everything seems to work.
Then, I tried to show the custom view in a UIScrollView inside a UITableViewCell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RecessCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Recess"];
    if(cell == nil) cell = (RecessCell *)[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Recess"];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1, 320, 50)];
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 50);
    [scrollView addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RecessCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
    [cell addSubview:scrollView];
    return (UITableViewCell *)cell;
}
```

Of course, it didn't work. Every time I load the xib I get the annoying run-time error, that again and again makes me want to kill myself :

> '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key betweenPeriods.'
>   While SetupRecess is the UIViewController class.
>   SetupRecess shouldn't have an outlet for betweenPeriods - RecessCell should.

That's why I tried to change the owner in the loadNib method to cell.
Well, guess what? DIDNT WORK.

> '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key betweenPeriods.'

I'm totally frustrated, as you can see. I really have no idea what's the problem, and obviously not how to fix it.

Please help,
thank you.

Comment: You're using the custom class RecessCell, but you are alloc and initing a UITableViewCell. It's not enough to cast to the class, you actually need to create an object of that class.

Comment: It's also telling you that `betweenPeriods` is not a KVC compliant property.

Comment: @Abizern The 2nd assertion is only partially true, te real problem is what you explained in #1.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
         RecessCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Recess"];
         if(cell == nil) {

                 NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RecessCell" owner:self options:nil];
                 cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
                 cell.showsReorderControl=NO;
                 cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                 cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
             } 
             UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1, 320, 50)];
             scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
             scrollView.bounces = NO;
             scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

             scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 50);
             [scrollView addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RecessCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
             [cell addSubview:scrollView];

             return cell;
         }
```